# EF Code First migrations alternative for ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, orm, dapper

I have one question related to database migrations framework for ASP.NET Core.

So we have beautiful Entity Framework and there we have code first migrations and in this case all works great for us.
BUT, I'm using Dapper ORM instead of EF for my application and in this case I can't use EF Migrations. So I need something like [flywaydb migrations](https://flywaydb.org/) but for ASP.NET Core application.

Do you know some frameworks which can help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is my solutions:

[fluentmigrator](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator)

[DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/)

But still need to investigate this solutions a bit more.

Comment: Hey,check out my project SharpMigrations too :) https://github.com/sharpmigrations/sharpmigrations/tree/2.0

Answer (score 1):

You're not using EF at all, you say. Why don't you use a Visual Studio database project. If you have an existing DB, you import it into the DB project. Thereafter, you make your changes in the DB project, then push them out to your instances via the schema comparison and scripting tools. Your DB project can live in your VS solution. Have I understood the problem correctly?

Comment: another point is that DB project is supported only under Windows

Comment: DB projects and dacpac deployment are only for SQL Server, but your SQL Server can be on Linux or Azure. Are you saying that VB for mac doesn't have DB projects? This wouldn't be a big surprise, but I don't think many folk are affected. Maybe I need to get out more?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Update-Database -Script
```

on your migration command to obtain the sql code

Comment: Yes, but `Update-Database -Script` it's a Entity Framework command as I know.

But in my case I getting rid of EF at all, so I need some other approach to apply database migration.